# If Java improved on C++, why cant it be called a suitable replacement?

Tags: java, c++

After reading the Java White Paper, I have a question on my mind and it might not be a very smart question but here it is anyway:
From what I gathered, Java attempted to improve an a number of fallacies associated with C++ such as redundancy, confusion with pointers, full-object orientation etc.,
If Java managed to overcome these issues, why would it be incorret to say that Java can replace C++.

Comment: Oh, if this stays opened, I smell a really big conflict upcoming.

Comment: 'if java improved on c++' - wow it's almost so far round the naive scale as to be verging on genius

Comment: You should watch: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2011-Herb-Sutter-Why-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many situations where C++ is a better option than Java. Comparison [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C++).

Specifically:

> In addition to running a compiled Java program, computers running Java
>   applications generally must also run the Java Virtual Machine JVM,
>   while compiled C++ programs can be run without external applications.
>   Early versions of Java were significantly outperformed by statically
>   compiled languages such as C++. This is because the program statements
>   of these two closely related languages may compile to a few machine
>   instructions with C++, while compiling into several byte codes
>   involving several machine instructions each when interpreted by a JVM.
>
> Certain inefficiencies are inherent to the Java language itself,
>   primarily:
>
> 1. All objects are allocated on the heap. For functions using small objects this can result in performance degradation as stack
>      allocation, in contrast, costs essentially zero. However, this
>      advantage is obsoleted by modern JIT compilers utilising escape
>      analysis or escape detection to allocate objects on the stack. Escape
>      analysis was introduced in Oracle JDK 6.
> 2. Methods are by-default virtual. This slightly increases memory usage by adding a single pointer to a virtual table per each object.
>      Also, it induces a startup performance penalty, because a JIT compiler
>      has to do additional optimization passes even for de-virtualization of
>      small functions.
> 3. A lot of casting required even using standard containers induces a performance penalty. However, most of these casts are statically
>      eliminated by the JIT compiler, and the casts that remain in the code
>      usually do not cost more than a single CPU cycle on modern processors,
>      thanks to branch prediction.
> 4. Array access must be safe. The compiler is required to put appropriate range checks in the code. Naive approach of guarding each
>      array access with a range check is not efficient, so most JIT
>      compilers generate range check instructions only if they cannot
>      statically prove the array access is safe. Even if all runtime range
>      checks cannot be statically elided, JIT compilers try to move them out
>      of inner loops to make the performance degradation as low as possible.
> 5. Lack of access to low level details does not allow the developer to better optimize the program where the compiler is unable to do
>      so.[10]. Programmers can interface with the OS directly by providing
>      code in C or C++ and calling that code from Java by means of JNI.

Also as an iOS/Mac dev, and strong background in DSP, and lover of many open source C++ and Objective C libraries, I could go on and on as to why Java is not better...

Comment: A selection of myths halfvttutgs.

Comment: Unless you give some specifics, your comment isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Java didn't have the same goals and so doesn't serve the same function as C++. In other words, Java may have made some improvements, but also some regressions in things that are important for C++ applications.

Therefore Java cannot simply replace C++.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is kind of off-topic for this forum (it's not about a programming problem). Nevertheless, here's my two cents.

Java and C++ serve different needs. For instance, while pointers in C++ (as in C) are certainly complicated, it is precisely because of pointers that one can manipulate specific addresses in memory. This is quite valuable for certain applications and impossible to do in Java (without resorting to native methods—often implemented in (ahem) C++).

C++ is compiled into machine code native to the machine. Java is compiled into machine-independent byte code. Thus C++ tends to have a speed advantage. This is offset somewhat, but not entirely, by just-in-time compilers for Java.

I'm sure others here will post additional differences between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Java is a reasonably good application development platform.

It is not a systems development platform.  It can't provide direct access to hardware.  It can't be used to implement a Java Virtual Machine (chicken and egg problem).

So you will always need a language that compiles to native code in order to bootstrap your high-level runtime.

Comment: Of course you can implement a JVM in Java, just like you can implement the C++ runtime library in C++. It's a bootstrapping problem, not a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @TedHopp: Wrong.  This isn't about compilation, this is about execution.  The C++ runtime library, written in C++, compiles to native code, and needs no help at runtime.  The Java Virtual Machine, if it were written in Java, would be bytecode.  Java bytecode can't execute until a JVM is running (interpreter or JIT, doesn't matter).  You can't use bytecode until the JVM is running, and a JVM written in Java can't run until bytecode is working.  Chicken and egg.

Comment: @BenVoigt, if C or C++ needs no help, try deleting libc before you run your program. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: My kernel is written in C and C++, it doesn't require libc.  And yes, I've written C programs which don't require libc.  Anyway, what I said is that libc and libc++ need no help.

Comment: @BenVoigt, While you can create a C program which doesn't require system libraries to be installed first, this is not reality for most C applications. Similarly, you can compile Java to an exe, but this is rarely done.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: You can translate Java to other environments, but then it isn't Java any longer.  We're not talking about whether an application can run without supporting libraries.  We're talking about whether those supporting libraries will run if written in the application language.  For C and C++, yes.  For Java, no, the runtime can't be Java bytecode.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the extent may be lower but even in C you are going to need some code written in assembly. You can't write a kernel in pure C++ or even pure C.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That just strengthens the claim I made in my answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @BenVoigt, If it doesn't I misunderstood it, I am sorry.  My claim; unless you use assembly, your code is going to need support from a framework, libraries or sections of code written in another language at some point. You could take the view that a C++ Runtime Library and a Java Platform are fundamentally different, or you could take the view that is something which you application depends on to run. IMHO Its historical that the C library is considered part of the OS, the C++ library is treated much the same and the JVM is separate even though most UNIX install it by default as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: So Java doesn't replace lower-level languages because "you will always need a language that compiles to native code in order to bootstrap your high-level runtime."  You can run a solitary JVM written in C++.  You can't run a solitary JVM in Java, at best it can be a second-layer JVM.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Similarly, you can't run a solitary program written in C++, you will always depend on something else which uses assembly.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: that depends on your toolchain.  There are quite a few platforms where I can directly code in C and C++, with the right linker options of course to place my startup code at the right offset.  But those are build time, no support code needed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ is often still a factor faster in applications and the JRE hasn't been ported to all platforms/OS's.

Other than that, not everyone agrees that, just from a design perspective, Java is an improvement on C++.

Comment: C++ hasn't been ported to all platforms/OS's either. (Good luck programming in C++ for a BlackBerry, for instance.)

Comment: @TedHopp: Who are you kidding?  https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/  The OS is written in C++ (except for a little bit of assembler), and it's also the best language for high-performance apps.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Don't you say that. C++ IS ported on blackberry, don't say just because blackberry disabled the execution of third party C++ code that it isn't ported, that's just wrong.

Comment: @Ben -- I was thinking about BB smartphones. You are right that one can program in C++ for the Playbook; I don't believe there is any such thing for their smartphones. I stand by my main point though -- developers cannot program in C++ for BlackBerry smartphones. Also, just because the OS is written in C++ doesn't mean that C++ programs will run in the OS.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: A turret is not portable, you can't carry it around. A gun is, you can. Carrying a gun around is illegal in my country, does that make a gun any less portable? Nope. Same goes for C++ on BB.

Comment: @TedHopp: Blackberry employees can develop in C++ for BB smartphones, therefore C++ is ported to those phones.  QED.  Being publicly available is not a necessary condition for "ported".

Comment: @Ben - That begs the question of what platform we're talking about. The BB smartphone is really a different platform for third-party developers than it is for BB employees (or at least those doing system-level programming). Even members of the elite tier of BB's alliance program don't have access to C++ tools. You're talking apples and oranges. In any event, the main point I was trying to make was that C++ is not a viable option for OP, for you, or for me if we're targeting BB smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

The main answer is probably that the language syntax is not what matters the most. C++ is designed to be compiled as native applications, while Java is designed to be compiled as Java bytecode applications, which run on a Java Virtual Machine.